# Jest NodeJS - Any way to put mocks in test directory?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have an application that I am testing with Jest.  Of course, for unit testing, it is useful to create mocks for dependencies.  However, as components of my application are interdependent (e.g. a service that requires a DAO), I need to mock them.  Currently, as documented in the Jest docs, I have a **mocks** directory in my source tree to hold the mock code.  However, I would like my test code to be separate from my source code.  Is there any way to configure Jest which will allow me to have my test code together and my source code together?  For example:

What I have:

```
- src
-- service
--- service.js
-- db
--- dao.js
--- __mocks__
---- dao.js
- test
-- service
--- service.test.js
```

What I want:

```
- src
-- service
--- service.js
-- dao
--- dao.js
- test
-- __mocks__
--- dao.js
-- service
--- service.test.js
```

Comment: [testRegex](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring) configuration support it by default. Did you try it?

Comment: That appears to be for changing the test directory itself.  That's not what I want to do, my tests are being detected properly.  I just want to bundle my mocks with my tests.